# eclipse auto-completion feature with descriptive argument names

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

i use eclipse as IDE for writing java programs. i can use auto-completion feature of course, for example, when i want to open a JOptionPane, auto-complete show it for me as below

[image]

as you see it just show available fitting methods, argument list, and type of each methods argument \, but each argument is written as arg0, arg1,... !

but recently i watch a video tutorial and i see that auto-completion feature in lecturer system show everything like mine, except that it doesn't show arguments as arg0, arg1, ... , but give them an descriptive name! like below:

[image]

i wonder how can i make my eclipse auto-completion to use a descriptive name for each argument, since it's so helpful I think.
thanks

Comment: Is your project's Java Build Path's JRE System Library pointing to a JRE or a JDK?

Comment: @nitind i don't know exactly what you mean, i'm new to java programming and now i'm writing a simple java swing app. if i can answer to what you ask plz tell me from where i can figure it out.

Comment: This is a question about the project's setup. In the Package Explorer, you should see an entry for a "JRE System Library" that refers to the Java runtime your own code is compiled against. Is it a JDK or a JRE? Since you're developing Java, it's best if it's a JDK.

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ choose a JDK instead of a JRE as default JRE. A JDK is a JRE plus the sources and some tools for Java development. A JDK is required here to show the parameter names and the Javadoc.

Comment: @nitind i see, it is JRE! but i don't think it is the reason! because in lecturer system it was JRE too! but he has descriptive arguments and me not

Comment: While there are ways to attach documentation and sources to a JRE from the mentioned preference page, this stuff tends to work correctly and automatically with a JDK. You're developing Java code, you should have the JDK anyway.

Comment: @howlger thanks, but in the lecturer system who has descriptive auto-complement it was JRE too!

Comment: @nitind thanks nitind, so how can i upgrade it to JDK?

Comment: You install a JDK separately, there is no upgrading from a JRE to a JDK. Once installed, use the preference page to set up an entry for the JDK and then right click on the JRE System Library in your project and change it to use the JDK entry.